# How to open large files with PhpStorm 8?

Tags: phpstorm, large-files

I'm dealing with **large SQL or XML files (can be up to 3GB)** that I would like to open in my editor. I get the message:

> File <the name of the file> is too large for PhpStorm editor

I have **32GB of RAM and Windows 7 Pro - 64bits**.

Can I override that limit?

Comment: Better use another editor for opening such HUGE files (anything above 10MB or so is already big). This IDE is not made for working with such HUGE files: it does much more than just text editing (syntax highlighting, syntax validation etc) and this "much more" consumes a lot of memory. Any file (e.g. `.php`) with 5000+ lines already feels slow when editing. Working with such large file may simply be impossible... (it's even recommended to exclude folders with large files from being indexed by IDE).

Comment: In any case: you can try increasing `idea.max.intellisense.filesize` property in `PHPSTORM_INSTALL/bin/idea.properties` file (2500KB is the default value). As mentioned [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-110674#comment=27-553663) *"Max opened file size is dependent on amount heap given to VM running PhpStorm, increasing heap size will allow the file to be opened."*, plus you have to use 64-bit JDK to even try opening such big file (PhpStorm by default uses own 32bit JDK).

Answer (score 19):

1. Help > Edit Custom Properties
2. For a max 400mb file, add line:

   ```
   idea.max.intellisense.filesize=400000
   ```
3. Restart phpstorm.

However, my computer has 16gb of ram, and a 333mb file still caused phpstorm to freeze up for a couple minutes.

Answer (score 12):

Like already said, `idea.max.intellisense.filesize` did it for me too, but I haven't tried it with such huge files, only with files like 300MB size.

Comment: Link to PHPStorm documentation on where and how to edit idea.max.intellisense.filesize: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/file-idea-properties.html

Comment: i have increased idea.max.intellisense.filesize to 100MB
Then ask me to increase the Xmx, and i make it 3000
and become very slow

Comment: @AhmedAlBermawy, maybe you should consider to use another editor then, a fully blown IDE ist not the best tool for files of this size

Comment: i used sublime :)